# How can I make a Discord bot require x permissions when adding it? Using Python

Tags: python, bots, discord

Maybe this is a noob question, really easy, but I have no idea how to do it.
For sure, you've seen other Discord bots, when you add them, they require certain permissions like "Administrator", "kick lower ranked members", "Manage messages", etc.

This would be easier to server's owner to setup the bot. Instead of they have to create a role, then setup those permissions, he could just tick them.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? Or are you asking about building something from scratch? If the latter this question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this calculator https://discordapi.com/permissions.html , tick the boxes for the permissions you would like the bot to request upon someone clicking the invite link. Once you've gotten the number, add it to the end of your invite link where it has `permissions=`